# Odd answer that is considered high quality in review audit

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was just asked to review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21771366/603661), which turned out to be a review audit.  I pressed the comment button to remark about this portion of the answer:

> <strike>Based on  [Interleave bits by Binary Magic
>   Numbers](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN)
>   from Sean Anderson's great page.</strike>
>
> ```
> b = ((c * 0x0101010101010101ULL & 0x8040201008040201ULL) * 
>      0x0102040810204081ULL >> 49) & 0x5555 ;
> b |= b<<1;
> ```
>
> You could also try any of the other Interleave Bits methods on that
>   page, just remember to set `y==0`

I wanted to ask for the person to either remove the text that had a strike-through or at least edit it out of the answer, since I saw no reason or explanation for its inclusion and appeared to be from a past edit.  However, by simply pressing the Comment button, I failed the review audit, since this answer has a score of 12.

Should it really be included as a "good first post" audit example?  I realize such answers are included in a mostly or entirely automated fashion and that some odd quirks like this one will end up getting included in the audit process, but this one in particular really bothered me.  Is there any way to manually omit this particular answer from future audits?

Comment: could it be struck out because it was an accepted answer and thus undeleteabe?

Comment: Nope, it's not the accepted answer for that question.

Comment: Well, it's fixed now.  I removed the struck out portion.